# Callback not working from thread Python

Tags: python, multithreading, callback

I have a tinker IMU and I'm using their library which is utilizing a callback to output data.  I want to do this all on a separate thread but the callback function is not being called when I try.  What am I doing wrong?

```
def myIMUCallback():
    print("callback called")


# Function to start recording IMU data via callback function
def startIMUData():
    HOST = "localhost"
    PORT = 4223
    UID = "6Dcx3Y" # Change XXYYZZ to the UID of your IMU Brick 2.0

    ipcon = IPConnection() # Create IP connection
    imu = BrickIMUV2(UID, ipcon) # Create device object

    ipcon.connect(HOST, PORT) # Connect to brickd
    # Don't use device before ipcon is connected

    # Register all data callback to function cb_all_data
    imu.register_callback(imu.CALLBACK_ALL_DATA, myIMUCallback)

    # Set period for all data callback to 0.1s (100ms)
    imu.set_all_data_period(100)

# This doesn't work, callback is not called
threadIMU = Thread(target = startIMUData, args = ())
threadIMU.daemon = True
threadIMU.start

# This works
startIMUData()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do `threadIMU.start()` not `threadIMU.start`